# How do I configure class options for latex export in my .emacs?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-export

By default org mode seems to configure 8x11 as the paper type when I export to latex.  I always print to A4, so I would like all of my exports to specify a4 as the paper type -- e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
```

I currently solve the problem by putting the following line in my file whenever I want to export, but that's pretty redundant:

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper]
```

How can I tell emacs to do this whenever I run latex export?

Comment: I believe that the default is taken from the default LaTeX clas, i.e. `#+LaTeX_CLASS: article` I think. See the value of `org-latex-default-class` to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 7):

You need to configure the `org-latex-classes` variable.
Usually something like the following does the trick:

```el
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
         '("article" "\\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}"
            ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
            ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
            ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
            ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
            ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

However, there already is a default class called `article`.
Editing that entry in the list is not recommended.

So I suggest creating your own, say `a4article`, by replacing `"article"` in the above example with `"a4article"`.
You can find many other examples in my [Emacs setup](https://github.com/suvayu/.emacs.d/blob/master/org-mode-config.el#L190).

Comment: Is editing inplace necessary? One can usually push a new element to the almost and the older one will be ignored

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, do you mean, why not add a duplicate "article" entry in `org-latex-classes`? As it's a list, duplicate entries can lead to unpredictable behaviour. If you rather edit in-place, have a look at my emacs setup (link provided in the answer), there are some examples for that as well (for a different `org-latex` variable).

Comment: I mean that this variable is documented to be an "Alist" (I just checked).  When searching an association list for an association with a given key, the first one found is returned, if there is more than one. (see `(info "(elisp) Association Lists")`).

Comment: There are too many brackets around the second argument of `add-to-list`.   Should be `(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes '("article" ... `.

Comment: Yep, you can just tack something on and it will override the default. I suggested an edit to fix the extra parentheses