# Org LaTeX export: set default options for documentclass

Tags: org-export

Is there variable like `org-latex-default-class-options` which will set default options for `\documentclass` like file variable `#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS` do?

This situation similar to variables `#+LATEX_CLASS` and `org-latex-default-class`.  I've found [How do I configure class options for latex export in my .emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16864/how-do-i-configure-class-options-for-latex-export-in-my-emacs), but it's one-year-old and not so trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Into the documentation "Org Mode/Exporting/LaTeX export/LaTeX header and sectioning structure":

> By default, the LaTeX output uses the class article.
>
> You can change this globally by setting a different value for `org-latex-default-class` or locally by adding an option like `#+LATEX_CLASS: myclass` in your file, or with a `EXPORT_LATEX_CLASS` property that applies when exporting a region containing only this (sub)tree. The class must be listed in `org-latex-classes`.

Comment: Why did you answer your own question with a non-answer?