# Change style of Org-Mode export to pdf

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf

I'm new to Org-Mode and Spacemacs and I'm trying to change the export style of org-mode. I want to take notes with it and have source code blocks.

I'm having difficulty in changing the export template. If possible, I would also like to know how can I import a `.cls` file in the same folder and use that as a template.

I have tried this three codes but it doesn't work:

- `#+LATEX_CLASS: org_mode_document_style`: it cannot find the template
- `#+LATEX_HEADER: \documentclass{org_mode_document_style}`: doesn't show
- `#+LATEX:\documentclass{org_mode_document_style}`: doesn't show

So, I have this page in PDF and as you can see, some text is off the page, how can I correct this behavior? How can I transform the page on top in something like the page on the bottom?

[image: Target template]

Comment: I recommend you split your question into 2 or 3 different ones, since there are really separate issues here.

Comment: `#+LATEX_CLASS` should be ok.  The problem may not be with org export but with latex.  Try exporting to a latex file rather than pdf, then compile the latex file to see what's wrong.

Comment: @JeanPierre It says `unknown class named org_mode_document_style`. Just to remind, the file `org_mode_document_style.cls` is in the same folder   of the `.org` file.

Comment: I was wrong, org needs to know about the class, see doc of `LATEX_CLASS` at http://orgmode.org/org.html#LaTeX-specific-export-settings.

Comment: See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16870/2093) to get an idea how to configure your own `LATEX_CLASS`.